# File.Delete() loop hanging every now and then

Tags: c#, delete-file

So I have an app, that needs at one point to empty a directory of all it's files. It takes pictures and places them in a folder. Since I do not want to deal with existing files logic, I prefere to empty the folder before doing the capturing.
So naturally, at that point I call a method that does that.
Here is my method:

```
private void emptyMyFolder()
{
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(textBox1.Text + @"\my\rest\of\the\path\here\");
    foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
    {
        file.Delete();
    }
}
```

And it works just fine. Except, every now and then, this method hangs for very long time.
I moved the method call in a onClick button, to isolate it and exclude other possible factors. And still, from time to time, this method call hangs and the application becomes unresponsive.

What is strange, is that if while the application is not responding, I navigate with Windows Explorer to that folder that needs to be emptied, I see most of the files there... I select them all, and try to delete them manually... but after hitting Delete, Windows itself waits 5-10 seconds, and then it tells me that the file I want to delete does not exist (because clearly, the process in my not-responding application succeeded in deleting them). And yes, after Windows tells me that, I can see that the folder is empty and that my application became responsive.

Sometimes, if I do NOT use Explorer to try and force-delete the files manually, my application hangs for minutes... And everytime, there are only 35-38 files in that folder. And the file size is at max 700kB for each file. So it should not be any problem.
And also, sometimes, this method call takes a fraction of a second...

I use Windows 10 for development, and my app is made with VisualStudio 2015 Community. The app is deployed to another computer also with Windows 10...

Can anyone help me solve this?

I would rather not try to delete the folder contents using a BAT script file...

Comment: Do you have antivirus that may be bothersome? If you can reproduce the problem with some certainty try disabling your antivirus program or adding an exception for that folder and see if that helps.

Comment: Nope, no antivirus, (I mean I disabled it to test your suggestion, but no change in behaviour) and yes, I run the application as Administrator just in case there might be rights issues...

Comment: Are these files on _Dropbox_?

Comment: Probably not the case, but you aren't by any chance using any of the files that you want to delete in another application?

Comment: No, files are local (not Dropbox). And no, I do not use the files anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

How about `Directory.Delete(path, true)` then you don't have to iterate the files. Also, `di.GetFiles()` may get called during each iteration. If you want to delete the files using a loop, snap it to a list first: `var files = di.GetFiles().ToList();` Now it won't try to figure out the file list during each iteration which may be causing the lock.

Comment: I can't use Directory.Delete because I only want the files to be deleted, not the subfolders too. I will try the List() suggestion and come back to you

Comment: Directory.Delete iterates the files as well.  There is no way to delete an entire directory in one go in Windows

Comment: `GetFiles()` returns an array. There's no need to convert it to a list